# How to expand or fit array of divs using grid in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, grid, css-position

So, Ive been working this for a days and I cant find on how to expand my remaining divs using grid. I used an array (map) to iterate my array of objects thats why I cant figure it out because all I know only is by targeting every div and set property grid-row/grid-column to be able them to fit. This is new to me because I cant target them because its iterating. Im using react in case you wonder why I iterate them.

```
  {data.map(item => {
    return (
      <Item
        key={item.id}
        title={item.title}
        description={item.description}
      />
    );
  })}
```

// This is my style for Card.

```
div.container-card{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 250px 250px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

The output is I got 6 card next to each other in the top, and 4 at the bottom. What I want is I want to expand those remaining 4 at the bottom to fit in the whole width. Any idea guys because Im just a beginner(obviously).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive just added a background width to the background:

```
... {
 width: 80%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```